# Is there a solution to centralize access control (to entities) based on ownership and other user-document relations

Tags: php, symfony, architecture

Lets say i have a number of types of documents in my system. I want to restrict access to them based on three aspects: user roles, ownership and relevance of user to the object. So for example ROLE_DOCUMENTTYPE1READ will grant user a right to read document (other roles such as ROLE_DOCUMENTTYP1WRITE will grant RW rights). Presence of connection to the document (if document has user in his 1:M related_users field) gives user right to add comments to document. And if user is owner of the object he can edit it entirely.

I can easily implement it in controller or even create a trait or something like this, but it would be too ugly and also tedious because there will be lots of entities and actions upon them, not only regular CRUD, but also additional one's that change certain fields. I want to know how usually such things should be done. Maybe there are some architectural patterns that help in this situation? Right now, as i already said, i'm going to check in every action if user is related to entity or if he is even its owner or has said roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the JMSSecurityExtraBundle and the [Expression-based Authorization Language](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/expressions). *They allow to perform complex access decision checks, and because they are compiled down to raw PHP, they are much faster than the built-in voters.*

Comment: Actually i already working on that :) Also their AOP bundle is handy for this task too. For now i decided to implement what i can in custom Security expression (because my controllers use Id's instead of objects) and use already existing one's. But thank you anyways :)